# "Étalé space almost looks like a sheaf"

Tags: sheaf-theory

In Daping Weng's [*A Categorical Introduction to Sheaves*](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/WengD.pdf), in the paragraph preceding section 3.2 (page 8), the author says

> A sheaf space [= Étalé space] almost looks like a sheaf...

I would very much like to understand why the author says this and how I can see it for myself. In what sense does the Étalé space "almost look like a sheaf"?

The only bit I can see for myself goes through the agricultural analogy that the Étalé space gathers germs into stalks, which takes us a step closer to sheaves. Indeed, the author says the only remaining thing to do is to "tie" the stalks together, which is supposedly what the sheaf-of-cross-sections functor does. However, I how does "each cross section over an open set is open and homeomorphic to the underlying set" make the Étalé space "look like a sheaf"?

Comment: Etale spaces *are* sheaves (in the sense that the category of etale spaces over $X$ and the category of sheaves on $X$ are equivalent). I don't know if the author meant anything else.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I do not think this is what the author meant. I think he is analysing the sheafification functor by breaking it down into the Étalé space functor and then the sheaf-of-cross-section functor. The Étalé space functor collects germs into stalks, and the sheaf-of-cross-sections "ties them up". The author uses this terminology, and I think he does mean something else. (maybe I'm wrong :p)

Comment: I thought the topology on the étalé space is what ties the stalks together. A local section just selects a germ from each stalk.